# Setup method JUnit 5 TestSuite

Tags: java, installation, junit5, test-suite

I am trying to executes some tests using JUnit 5 Test Suite. Based on the documentation I found, I used `@RunWith` and `@SelectPackages` (from the dependency junit-platform-runner).

Before I started the tests defined in the `@SelectPackages`, I wanted to load some properties file in such a setup method. I tried using `@BeforeAll`, `@ClassRule` and `@Rule`, but those setup methods are only called in any test methods in the annotated class (`RemoteTests`). But the setup methods are not called before the executions of the test classes defined in the `@SelectPackages` (`com.test.packages`).

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("com.test.packages") 
public class RemoteTests {
    @Rule // I tried also @ClassRule and @BeforeAll here
    public void setup() {
        PropertiesLoader.loadProperties("remote.properties");
    }
}
```

Are there any setup annotations for my purpose?

Comment: JUnit5 has no `@RunWith` (it has `@ExtendWith`) nor `@Rule`. Maybe you are mixing annotations with JUnit4?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
You might be right, because the dependency tree contains junit 4 also. But I only followed the instruction in several websites, such as https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5 (chapter 7. Test Suites).

Does @ExtendWith works exactly as @RunWith? Or is there any possibilities to start a test suite in JUnit 5?

Comment: See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith) chapter 4. So are you running JUnit4 tests in JUnit5. Or vice versa.

Comment: Hi pirho, thanks.

For me it is preferable to run everything in JUnit5, but I cannot find any information on how to have TestSuite it in a pure JUnit5 environment.

Anyway in worst case, it is enough for me to use JUnit4, but I could not make it to run the tests with some setup method, where I would like some properties file before executing the tests. 

In the given example from your link, there is not shown how to put some setup method before the tests.

I have tried using `@BeforeClass`, `@ClassRule`, `@BeforeAll`, but nothing helped :(